# How to make vuetify v-data-table vertically span all available space

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

Is it possible to make v-data-table vertically span all available space and pagination bar stick to the bottom like on "Desired layout" snapshot

[image: Desired layout]

[Here is my codepen where commented html shows what I've tried already](https://codepen.io/javapantry/pen/yZgxJp)

```
<div id="app">
              <v-data-table 
                            :items='alarms' 
                            :headers="headers"
                            class="elevation-1"
                            fill-height>
                <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
                  <td>{{ props.item.fridgeDisplayName }}</td>
                  <td>{{ props.item.state }}</td>
                  <td>{{ props.item.task }}</td>
                </template>
              </v-data-table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the official docs there's no way to do that but you could do it simply using CSS by adding the following rules :

```
.theme--light.v-datatable .v-datatable__actions {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      //pagination: {},
      headers: [{
          text: 'Name',
          value: 'fridgeDisplayName'
        },
        {
          text: 'State',
          value: 'state'
        },
        {
          text: 'Task',
          value: 'task'
        },
      ],
      alarms: [{
          fridgeDisplayName: 'Test1',
          state: 'Some state',
          task: '6.0'
        },
        {
          fridgeDisplayName: 'Test2',
          state: 'Some state',
          task: '6.0'
        },
        {
          fridgeDisplayName: 'Test3',
          state: 'Some state',
          task: '6.0'
        },
        {
          fridgeDisplayName: 'Test4',
          state: 'Some state',
          task: '6.0'
        },
        {
          fridgeDisplayName: 'Test5',
          state: 'Some state',
          task: '6.0'
        },
        {
          fridgeDisplayName: 'Test6',
          state: 'Some state',
          task: '6.0'
        },
        {
          fridgeDisplayName: 'Test7',
          state: 'Some state',
          task: '6.0'
        },
        {
          fridgeDisplayName: 'Test8',
          state: 'Some state',
          task: '6.0'
        },
        {
          fridgeDisplayName: 'Test9',
          state: 'Some state',
          task: '6.0'
        },
        {
          fridgeDisplayName: 'Test10',
          state: 'Some state',
          task: '6.0'
        },
        {
          fridgeDisplayName: 'Test11',
          state: 'Some state',
          task: '6.0'
        },
        {
          fridgeDisplayName: 'Test12',
          state: 'Some state',
          task: '6.0'
        },
        {
          fridgeDisplayName: 'Test13',
          state: 'Some state',
          task: '6.0'
        },
        {
          fridgeDisplayName: 'Test14',
          state: 'Some state',
          task: '6.0'
        },
        {
          fridgeDisplayName: 'Test15',
          state: 'Some state',
          task: '6.0'
        },
        {
          fridgeDisplayName: 'Test16',
          state: 'Some state',
          task: '6.0'
        },
        {
          fridgeDisplayName: 'Test17',
          state: 'Some state',
          task: '6.0'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    /*pages () {
      if (this.pagination.rowsPerPage == null ||
        this.pagination.totalItems == null
      ) return 0

      return Math.ceil(this.pagination.totalItems / this.pagination.rowsPerPage)
    }*/
  }
})
```

```css
.theme--light.v-datatable .v-datatable__actions {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.4.0/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.4.0/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<div id="app" data-app>
  <v-data-table :items='alarms' :headers="headers" class="elevation-1" fill-height>
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
                      <td>{{ props.item.fridgeDisplayName }}</td>
                      <td>{{ props.item.state }}</td>
                      <td>{{ props.item.task }}</td>
                    </template>
  </v-data-table>

</div>
```

the [`full pen code`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PVWXVm)

Comment: In codePen this CSS does the magic right after I've paste style into CSS section, But I have no clue where to apply this style in Vue+Vuetify application. Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you're using single file component .vue you could add in style section

Comment: add in <style> in component with datatable. Works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: Is there way to define it globally? Because I have too many components with tables in them.  .... Right <styles> without 'scoped' apply globally. Thanks!

Comment: create a file named `main.css` in assets folder and that rules inside it and import it in `main.js` like `import './assets/main.css'` after `import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'`